# How do I call a function at a specific time of a day?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to call the `studentUpdateAttendanceStart` action 10 minutes before a course's `endDate`. How can I do that?. The code below is what I currently have but the student needs to refresh the page. When I included `allowAttendanceUpdateAfter`, `courseDocId`, `endDate`, `id`, `now`, `startDate`, `student`, `studentTimestamp`, and `studentUpdateAttendanceStart` inside useEffect's dependency array `useEffect` got called multiple times because I was passing the `now` variable.

**What I'm trying to do**:
If a course starts at 10:30am and ends at 11:30am, from 11:20am to 11:30am, first check if the `student.attendanceStatus` is not empty and if the time is between 11:20am to 11:30am. Then check if student has been logged in for at least a certain amount of time to mark them as present else mark the student as absent. What is the best approach to this?. The code that I currently have works but the student needs to refresh the page.

```
const now = moment().toDate(),
    allowAttendanceUpdateAfter = moment(endDate).subtract(10, 'minutes');

useEffect(() => {
    if (
      now >= allowAttendanceUpdateAfter.toDate() &&
      now <= endDate &&
      !student.attendanceStatus.length
    ) {
      if (allowAttendanceUpdateAfter - startDate < now - studentTimestamp) {
        studentUpdateAttendanceStart(courseDocId, {
          ...student,
          id,
          attendanceStatus: 'Present'
        });
      } else {
        studentUpdateAttendanceStart(courseDocId, {
          ...student,
          id,
          attendanceStatus: 'Absent'
        });
      }
    }
  }, []);
```

Comment: If this is all happening on the client, can you wrap it in a `setInterval` an run it every minute until it hits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a cron job.

Wherever you're hosting the api of this application usually provides such service from the container where you would be able to make time specific periodic requests to the client via http or whatever other method of communication is supported by your host.

Comment: I'm currently using Heroku for hosting and using Express for my back-end. Can Express be configured to only send PUT request at a specific time?.

Comment: Yes, it can. Here is a link to it https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduler